# Find matches and replace in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two list in Excel sheet.

**A**

1. Computer
2. Hardware
3. Software

**B**

1. 000Hardware
2. 111Computer
3. 333Software

I want another column like

**C**

1. 111Computer
2. 000Hardware
3. 333Software.

That is search in column A find the match in column B and replace column C with the matched one.

Comment: Does B always start with 3 numbers before a word? If not are there sometimes letters in the bit before the word or just numbers. Will A ever have numbers in?

Comment: yes..First three postion may or maynot contain numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Column C, you want to put:

```
=VLOOKUP("***" & A1,B:B,1,FALSE)
```

You can then drag this down the column, the stars are wildcard characters. This is presuming that when you've wrote "1.", "2.", etc, you are referring to the row numbers.

This should work for no matter how many numbers come before the cell in the B column.